# DrawerLayout + Picasso разметка не соответствует действительности

Tags: java, android, picasso

Настраиваю использование NavigationView

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
iv_haederdrawer = (ImageView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.iv_haederdrawer);
Picasso.with(NewsActivity.this).load("http://cs635102.vk.me/v635102610/5f40/f0oxmR2iluw.jpg").into(iv_haederdrawer);
```

Разметка XML

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@color/drawerBackground"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:gravity="bottom">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:id="@+id/iv_haederdrawer"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:longClickable="true">
</ImageView>
```

Получается, что картинка вместо положенных 90 dp, занимает 100. И при этом не уменьшается в нужных пропорциях. Пробовал разные стили применять к картинке, ничего не помогает - куска не хватает(примерно 10 dp сверху). Меня больше всего удивляет, что разметка съезжает. Использую Lenovo 6010 Android 5.0.2. На планшете со старым андройдом 4.4.2 все отображается корректно. Прошу подсказать, где проблема. Интересно еще кто какие вы используете методы для уменьшения картинок.

Вот как по факту вышло:
[image: Съеденные 10dp]

Вот как хочу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы лучше прикрепили еще скриншоты как должно быть и как по факту вышло

Comment: пожкспериментируйте с атрибутом `android:scaleType="fitStart`

Comment: экспериментировал, это не в нем проблема!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас картинка уехала под statusBar. На андроиде выше 5-го navigationView может его перекрывать. И быть прозрачным. Скорее всего у вас где-то в стилях/разметке указано, что-то типа fitSystemWindows.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы! Огромное спасибо!